# How to append array data to array variable in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm calling API using HTTP connector getting result array data. and used until loop. so every time i will get some records into result array.

Now I want to append all records so that i will those all.

Like 1st time i got 2 records like below and 2nd time 1 then I want to append so that it will be 3 total.

1st iteration result -

```
"results":[
{"id":"2","name":"t1"},{"id":"3","name":"t4"}
]
```

2nd iteration result -

```
"results":[
  {"id":"66","name":"i7"}]
```

I want to append all data so that final result will be like -

```
[{"id":"2","name":"t1"},{"id":"3","name":"t4"}, {"id":"66","name":"i7"}]
```

instead of `foreach` I tried using `append array variable` but it throws below error -

its a type of array need to be string to append.
[image]

I can able to achieve it using foreach but it does not make sense just to add values use foreach instead if we found any way to directly add array it will be great.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JS inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#add-inline-code) to implement your requirement. I did some test on my side, post to arrays(result1 and result2) to logic app and compose them using JS : 
[image]

Result :

[image]

Please note if you want to use this feature , you should create an integration account and associated with your logic app in "Workflow settings" blade .

Comment: but for inline i need to use integration account is there any another way to do? using any expression ?

Comment: If you want to use js inline, integration account is needed,I am not sure if there will be any other ways , sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

The above solution works only if you have integration account.
Other simple option - use union function inside compose action to append two array collections:

union(variables('ResponseArray'),body('Response'))
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#union