# How to pass data to csv file from multiple json file in Logic app without appending data one by one?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Aim:  Transfer JSON data of multiple file from Storage container(One folder) into one CSV file in logic app with headers.

I have design the Logic app where this above functionality working fine. Json data from all three files in folder is able to pass to one CSV file .

I have used APPEND TO ARRAY VARIABLE connector and iterate the loop through no of file and content of file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the three json first and then use [union()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#union) method to merge the three json arrays.

[image]

Comment: This will remove duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS inline code or even offloading to an Azure Function to achieve your requirements.

**Steps to Add Inline Code**

**Step-1** Create your Logic App from Azure Portal

**Step-2** Select where to add the Inline code action in your workflow, you can add as a new step either at the end or in-between steps.

> [image]

**Step-3** Choose `inline code` and select the action **Execute JavaScript Code**. It contains some sample code, including a `return` statement.

> [image]
> [image]

**Step-4** Clear the code and enter the your code without method signature

> [image]

**Step-5** To make the results from the trigger and previous actions easier to reference, the dynamic content list appears when your cursor is inside the **Code** box. After you select the  **Body**  token, the inline code action resolves the token to a  `workflowContext`  object that references the email's  `Body`  property value:

> For this example, the list shows available results from the trigger, including the **Body** token, which you can now select.
> [image]

**Step-6** The Inline Code action doesn't require a `return` statement, but the results from a `return` statement are available for reference in later actions through the **Result** token.

> For example, the code snippet returns the result by calling the `match()` function, which finds matches in the email body against the regular expression. The **Compose** action uses the **Result** token to reference the results from the inline code action and creates a single result.
> [image]

**Step-7**  When you're done, save your logic app.

> Note : You need to create an integration account and connect with your Logic App from `workflow settings` blade in case you want to use this feature.

For adding Triggers, Actions or Parameters you can refer [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code#add-inline-code)

You can find more information in the SO [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125812/how-to-append-array-data-to-array-variable-in-logic-app) which discusses on similar related issue.

Comment: @Nikita Bhopale - Is the answer provided by SwethaKandikonda-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.